# How to use maven project as backend?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, jetty

I know this is basic stuff, but I couldn't figure it out with Google so here I am. I have a backend that allows for the use of web sockets on my website using jetty/java. When I want the backend to work, I have to cd into the project's directory and then run the command 'mvn jetty:run.' Before that, I have to add maven's bin file to the PATH variable. This is all done on an AWS instance. So what I'm wondering is, how do I have the maven package run on startup of the server (after running mvn package of course). Is there something I need to add to init.d? I'm really not sure.

Comment: Maven shouldn't have anything to do with this.  A better idea would be to use something like Spring Boot with an embedded Jetty/Tomcat server.  All you need is a JVM to run the executable JAR that Maven will create for you.

Comment: I'm running apache httpd as the main website. Are you saying I should install jetty alongside and just have it on a different port. Then have java execute the jar on startup?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should package and deploy your app as a Spring Boot executable JAR.  Running the app will mean executing the JAR on JDK 8.

Comment: I looked at Spring Boot's website. Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I'm understanding is, include Spring Boot in the maven pom file, package the maven project as a jar, then on startup have something like java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar run?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry one last question: when I did this, I got an error that said no main manifest attribute (I assume because I don't have a main method in any of my java files), but jetty's implementation of websockets doesn't require a main method, just a java file in it's own format (in case you aren't familiar here's a link to their format: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-server-api.html). What's really important though is how can I run the jar without the main method?

Comment: I'll add an answer to show the last bit you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an entry point, something like this:

```
package com.yourapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApp.class,args);
    }
}
```